# How replace the value inside a html tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, preg-replace

I want to replace element content with content which is definded in $tagsReplace array but have problem with preg_replace, my current ode:

```
$tagsReplace = array(
    'header' => 'header',
    'tag1' => 'this is tag1',
    'tag2' => 'this is tag2',
    'tag3' => 'this is tag3',
    'footer' => 'footer',
); 

$content = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hthml>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header"></header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3"></div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer"></footer>
</html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@data-edit="true"]') as $rowNode) { 
    $tagID = $rowNode->getAttribute('data-tag-id');
    $content = preg_replace('/(<div.*?data-edit="true"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/i', '$1'. $tagsReplace[$tagID] . '$3', $content);
}
echo $content;
```

What i want is to get output like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hthml>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header">header</header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1">this is tag1</div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2">this is tag2</div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3">this is tag3</div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer">footer</footer>
</html>
```

Current output is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<hthml>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header"></header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1">footer</div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2">footer</div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3">footer</div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer"></footer>
</html>
```

Soo all elements which contain atribute data-edit="true" and data-tag-id has to get content inside them replaced by tagid value which is definded in arra $tagsReplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are specifying 
**div**  in your preg_match pattern 
and we know that the first element starts with **header** so it won't be matched 
so simply replace the "div" at the beginning of the preg_match pattern with **(.*?)** to match header and even other words.
this :

$content = preg_replace('/(<**div**.*?data-edit="true"[^>]*>)(.*?)(</div>)/i', '$1'. $tagsReplace[$tagID] . '$3', $content);

becomes:

$content = preg_replace('/(<**(.*?)** data-edit="true"[^>]*>)(.*?)(</div>)/i', '$1'. $tagsReplace[$tagID] . '$3', $content);

Another option is available you can use **preg_replace_callback(pattern,function,subject)** to do what you want magically, here is a solution that worked for me :

```
$content = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hthml>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header"></header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3"></div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer"></footer>
</html>
';

$pattern = '/<(.+) data-edit="true" data-tag-id="(.*)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/(.+)>/';
$another = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){
    $tagsReplace = array(
        'header' => 'header1',
        'tag1' => 'this is tag1',
        'tag2' => 'this is tag2',
        'tag3' => 'this is tag3',
        'footer' => 'footer',
    ); 
    return '<'.$matches[1].' data-edit="true" data-tag-id="'.$matches[2].'"'.$matches[3].'>'.$tagsReplace[$matches[2]].'<\/'.$matches[5].'>/';
}, $content);
# before the replacement 
print_r($content);
echo '\n';
// another holds the content after replacement 
print_r($another);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the result you want you could loop through your replacement array and search for both `data-edit = true` and `data-tag-id = <key>` in the same XPath query, and then replace the node value. That way you do not have to use `preg_replace` at all.

```
$content = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header"></header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3"></div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer"></footer>
</html>
';

$tagsReplace = array(
    'header' => 'header',
    'tag1'   => 'this is tag1',
    'tag2'   => 'this is tag2',
    'tag3'   => 'this is tag3',
    'footer' => 'footer',
);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

foreach ($tagsReplace as $key => $value) {
    $nodes = $xpath->query(
        '//*[@data-edit="true" and @data-tag-id="' . $key . '"]'
    );

    if ($nodes->length) {
        $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue = $value;
    }
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header">header</header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1">this is tag1</div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2">this is tag2</div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3">this is tag3</div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer">footer</footer>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it accepts any type of tag

```
$tagsReplace = array(
    'header' => 'header',
    'tag1' => 'this is tag1',
    'tag2' => 'this is tag2',
    'tag3' => 'this is tag3',
    'footer' => 'footer',
); 

$content = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header"></header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3"></div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer"></footer>
</html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@data-edit="true"]') as $rowNode) {
    $tagID = $rowNode->getAttribute('data-tag-id');
    $content = preg_replace('/(<(.*?) [^>]*?data-tag-id="'.$tagID.'"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\2>)/i', '$1'. $tagsReplace[$tagID] . '$4', $content);
}
echo $content;
```

Comment: The portion of your regex which identifies the tagname allows it to go right outside that <>.  Better to specify something like `(?:div|header|footer)` or the like, or at least `[^ ]*` to stop when you get to a space.  Better yet would be to get the tagname ($rowNode->tagName ?) and then specify that specifically.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@data-edit="true"]') as $rowNode) {
    $rowNode->nodeValue = $tagsReplace[$rowNode->getAttribute('data-tag-id')];
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace always with the same patron because you have 3 differents tags.

Take a look to this code:

```
<?php

$tagsReplace = array(
    'header' => 'header',
    'tag1' => 'this is tag1',
    'tag2' => 'this is tag2',
    'tag3' => 'this is tag3',
    'footer' => 'footer',
); 

$content = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header"></header>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2"></div>
<div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3"></div>
<footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer"></footer>
</html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

$html = explode("\n", trim($content));
$i = 2;

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@data-edit="true"]') as $rowNode) { 
    $tagID = $rowNode->getAttribute('data-tag-id');

    switch ($rowNode->nodeName) {
        case 'header':
        $html[$i] = preg_replace('/(<header.*?data-edit="true"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/header>)/i', '$1'. $tagsReplace[$tagID] . '$3', $html[$i]);
        break;

        case 'div':
        $html[$i] = preg_replace('/(<div.*?data-edit="true"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/i', '$1'. $tagsReplace[$tagID] . '$3', $html[$i]);
        break;  

        case 'footer':
        $html[$i] = preg_replace('/(<footer.*?data-edit="true"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/footer>)/i', '$1'. $tagsReplace[$tagID] . '$3', $html[$i]);
        break;  
    }   
    $i++;
}

$content = implode("\n", $html);

echo $content;

?>
```

Comment: You're still going to get all 3 divs set to the same value because you haven't named the data-tag-id in the regex.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't notice you had exploded it into different lines and then were running the regex over each and every line individually. So you are right that it works with this exact data. However, what happens if you introduce something as simple as a blank line in front of one of the divs - there's nothing keeping the $i and the $rowNode in sync...

Comment: in this case this is not the best solution, but I just do what him need

Answer (score 1):

Do not use RegEx to parse/change HTML or XML. You already use the DOM, so why don't use it to change the document, too?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[@data-edit="true"]') as $rowNode) {
  // read id attribute 
  $tagId = $rowNode->getAttribute('data-tag-id');
  // remove all child nodes
  $rowNode->nodeValue = '';
  // if here is a new content available
  if (isset($tagsReplace[$tagId])) {
      // create a text node and append it
      $rowNode->appendChild(
         $dom->createTextNode($tagsReplace[$tagId])
      );
  }
}
echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Output (formatted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <header data-edit="true" data-tag-id="header">header</header>
    <div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag1">this is tag1</div>
    <div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag2">this is tag2</div>
    <div data-edit="true" data-tag-id="tag3">this is tag3</div>
    <footer data-edit="true" data-tag-id="footer">footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Warning!**: You HTML looks like HTML5 and that is not fully compatible to the PHP DOM implementation. You might need a [library](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php) to import/export the HTML5 to the DOMDocument as XHTML.